# FormCollection Fetch elements by data Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to get attibutes of `FormCollection`in `ActionMethod`. A form contains many inputs which are logically grouped with `data-*` attribute. So based on the `data` attribute, need to fetch elements from `FormCollection`.

eg:

```
<input type='text' data-group='GroupA' name='inp1' />
<input type='text' data-group='GroupA' name='inp2' />
<input type='text' data-group='GraupB' name='inp3' />
```

In action method

```
public ActionResult(FormCollection fc)
{
  --how to fetch elements which are in GroupA alone  
}
```

1. How to fetch elements which are in GroupA alone?

Any Ideas?

Comment: i dont think so hat is possible ....

Comment: @PranayRana, Yes `FormColleciton` will be posting back only `Key/Value` pairs back to `ActionMethod`, but there must be some tweak for this

Comment: tweak is you need to go for creating view with model

Comment: The current implementation can't go with `ViewModel`, need to get this worked out